# Defining a class of glyphs when some are not in the bold font

Tags: luatex, opentype

I discovered that adding the line `{\bf παπαῖ}` to the answer in [Defining an initial variant through a feature file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301835/defining-an-initial-variant-through-a-feature-file) results in a fatal error, because some of the glyphs in the class do not exist in the bold font. I tried to remedy this by defining a new feature ualt and using it just with the upright font. However, it seems that just defining the class and using bold Greek is enough to produce the error. (I even tried to put the class definition inside the feature.) Is there a way to avoid it?

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{junicode.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature ualt {
# (incomplete list)
@greekletter = [
Alphatonos anoteleia Epsilontonos Etatonos Iotatonos Omicrontonos Upsilontonos
Omegatonos iotadieresistonos Alpha Beta Gamma Delta Epsilon Zeta Eta Theta Iota
Kappa Lambda Mu Nu Xi Omicron Pi Rho Sigma Tau Upsilon Phi Chi Psi Omega
Iotadieresis Upsilondieresis alphatonos epsilontonos etatonos iotatonos
upsilondieresistonos alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta theta iota kappa
lambda mu nu xi omicron pi rho sigma1 sigma tau upsilon phi chi psi omega
iotadieresis upsilondieresis omicrontonos upsilontonos omegatonos uni03D0
theta1 phi1 omega1 uni03D7 uni03D8 uni03D9 uni03DA uni03DB uni03DC uni03DD
];
    sub @greekletter beta' by uni03D0;
} ualt;
\end{filecontents*}

\setmainfont[FeatureFile={junicode.fea}]{junicode}

\begin{document}
βιβλίον\par
\addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={RawFeature={+ualt}}}
βιβλίον\par
{\bf παπαῖ}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doubt this will solve the problem but `\bf` is 20+ years obsolete and ought not be used in LaTeX documents based on LaTeX 2e. `\bfseries` and `\textbf{}` are 2e's equivalents.

Comment: @cfr, oh. out of curiosity, is there any real difference?

Comment: Yes, there is. Compare `\bfseries\itshape` with `\bf\it`. In some classes, these give the same result - but only because the old commands have been redefined to be equivalent to the new ones. Otherwise, you'll get different results. `\bf`, `\it` etc. are still appropriate in plain TeX documents, of course, but ought not be used in LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Junicode Bold** font shape appears to contain just 3 glyphs in the "Greek and Coptic" group and 0 glyphs in the "Greek Extended" group. In contrast, the Junicode Upright (non-bold) font shape contains 88 and 233 glyphs in the "Greek and Coptic" and "Greek Extended" groups, respectively. Clearly, it's not fruitful to apply the feature file approach to **Junicode Bold**.

Fortunately, it is possible to limit the scope of the feature file to just the upright (non-bold) font shape of Junicode by replacing

```
\setmainfont[FeatureFile={junicode.fea}]{junicode}
...
\addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={RawFeature={+ualt}}}
```

with

```
\setmainfont{junicode}
...
\addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={FeatureFile={junicode.fea},
                                 RawFeature={+ualt}}}
```

Writing

```
\setmainfont[UprightFeatures={FeatureFile={junicode.fea}}]{junicode}
...
\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+ualt}}
```

works too.

In the following MWE, it's worth keeping in mind that no glyphs for `π`, `α`, or `ῖ` are provided by Junicode Bold. Hence, `παπαῖ` in the argument of `\textbf` doesn't show up in the screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{junicode.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature ualt {
# (incomplete list)
@greekletter = [
Alphatonos anoteleia Epsilontonos Etatonos Iotatonos Omicrontonos Upsilontonos
Omegatonos iotadieresistonos Alpha Beta Gamma Delta Epsilon Zeta Eta Theta Iota
Kappa Lambda Mu Nu Xi Omicron Pi Rho Sigma Tau Upsilon Phi Chi Psi Omega
Iotadieresis Upsilondieresis alphatonos epsilontonos etatonos iotatonos
upsilondieresistonos alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta theta iota kappa
lambda mu nu xi omicron pi rho sigma1 sigma tau upsilon phi chi psi omega
iotadieresis upsilondieresis omicrontonos upsilontonos omegatonos uni03D0
theta1 phi1 omega1 uni03D7 uni03D8 uni03D9 uni03DA uni03DB uni03DC uni03DD
];
    sub @greekletter beta' by uni03D0;
} ualt;
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{junicode}

\begin{document}
βιβλίον

\addfontfeature{UprightFeatures={FeatureFile={junicode.fea},
                                 RawFeature={+ualt}}}
βιβλίον

\textbf{παπαῖabc}
\end{document}
```